# Problemas com logica do insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Estou com um problema. Estou fazendo um sistema de controle de acesso de eventos, criei uma tabela que grava os dado id,codigo,data,hora,sit, o campo sit será 1 e 2, mas preciso que o meu sistema entenda o seguinte. Quando o ultimo registro do banco for 1 ele irá inserir o sit 2 e quando for 2 irá inserir o sit 1, segue abaixo minha estrutura.

```
<?php
    include"conect_db.php";

    $string_sql = mysql_select_db("evento"); //seleciona o banco de dados

    //Abaixo atribuímos os valores provenientes do formulário pelo método POS 
    $string_sql = ("select * from checkout where codigo='06181121978' order by id desc limit 1");
    mysql_query($string_sql,$conn); //Realiza a consulta

    if ($string_sql==$string_sql) {
        $teste = ("INSERT INTO checkout (id,codigo,data,hora,sit) VALUES (null,'06181121978',CURDATE(),curtime(),'1') <> (select * from checkout where codigo='06181121978' AND SIT='2' order by id desc limit 1");
        mysql_query($teste,$conn);
    }
    else{
        $teste2 = ("INSERT INTO checkout (id,codigo,data,hora,sit) VALUES (null,'06181121978',CURDATE(),curtime(),'2')");
        mysql_query($teste2,$conn);
    }
?>
```

Fiz assim , não deu erro mais tbm não registrou

```
$string_sql = mysql_select_db("evento"); //seleciona o banco de dados

//Abaixo atribuímos os valores provenientes do formulário pelo método POS 


$string_sql = ("select * from checkout where codigo='06181121978' order by id desc limit 1");
 mysql_query($string_sql,$conn); //Realiza a consulta

$resultado = mysql_query($string_sql, $conn);

$dado = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);

if ($dado['sit'] == '1') {
    // insere sit 2
    "INSERT INTO checkout (id,codigo,data,hora,sit) VALUES (null,'06181121978',CURDATE(),curtime(),'2')";
}
else {
    // insere sit 1
    "INSERT INTO checkout (id,codigo,data,hora,sit) VALUES (null,'06181121978',CURDATE(),curtime(),'1')";
}
```

Comment: `if ($string_sql==$string_sql) {` ? Faltou pegar o resultado da consulta e aplicar no if, cade o `mysql_fetch_assoc()` :P

Answer (score 1):

Existem alguns erros na sua lógica. A função `mysql_query()` deveria ser atribuída a uma variável que recebe seu resultado, por exemplo:

```
$resultado = mysql_query($string_sql, $conn);
```

Logo abaixo, no IF, você compara uma variável com ela mesma, enquanto deveria verificar se o resultado da consulta anterior o campo "sit" é 1 ou 2, por exemplo:

```
$dado = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);
if ($dado['sit'] == '1') {
    // insere sit 2
}
else {
    // insere sit 1
}
```

Não sei se entendi muito bem sua necessidade, caso não esteja claro, comente que atualizo a resposta.

Comment: fiz assim , não deu erro mais não gravou nada.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, neste caso é interessante você fazer uma query de update com condição, sem precisar impor lógica dentro do escopo do seu script.

Um exemplo:

```sql
UPDATE sua_tabela
SET sit = CASE
WHEN (SELECT sit FROM sua_tablea WHERE sua_condicao ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) = 1 THEN 2
ELSE 1
END
```

Neste exemplo eu executo o update, ao definir valor do campo eu executo um sub select, onde nele pego o último SIT, se for 1 eu coloco 1, se for 2 coloco 1.

Comment: mais vou usar em um formulario que ira receber o cidigo de barras, vai funcionar?

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida, Fernando. Na query de UPDATE eu apenas executei um sub select pegando o SIT do último registro e fazendo um IF ELSE para o valor do field. Basicamente eu retirei todo esse script que você fez para executar 3 querys para fazer isso, deixei a cargo do MYSQL.

Comment: Olá, consegui fazer, o problema era que quando criei a condição eu não tinha criado uma variável para o insert dentro do if e else, por isto não gravava os dados.

if ($dado['dados'] == '1') {
    // insere sit 2
  $query ="INSERT INTO lanca (id,dados) VALUES (null,'2')";
    $resultado = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
 
}
else {
    // insere sit 1
 $query ="INSERT INTO lanca (id,dados) VALUES (null,'1')";
    $resultado = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
 
}